# Bind Google Chart with Dynamic Datatable

Tags: .net, json, google-visualization

I am using the Google Pie Chart API for the first time. I need to bind it with my data table or JSON table, but it is not accepting any variable value.  Can anybody provide help regarding this issue?

Comment: Yes, please post your code so we can look for errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem and I think this would be helped. Please read below code FYI:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages : [ "corechart" ]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawPieChart);
function drawPieChart() {
    var options = {
        width : 720,
        height : 480,
        title : 'Chart'
    };

    $.getJSON("StockReceiver.jsp", function(json) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');

        $.each(json, function(i, item) {
            data.addRow([ new Date(item.date), item.open ]);
        });

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document
                .getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });
}
```